# excel macro to add value from cell to a table

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I am looking to use a macro to add the value of a certain cell in a worksheet to a table in another worksheet each time each time a button is pressed. For example, the first time the button is pressed I want the value of cell A1 in worksheet2 to be equal to cell C3 in worksheet1, next time B1 in worksheet2 is equal to C3 in worksheet1 , and so on. The macro should only add a value to the table if the cell thst it's being added to is empty.

This is what I have so far:

```
Sub Button32_ClickandUpdate
    myVariable = Worksheets("Worksheet1").Range("C3")

    For i = 1 To 6
        If IsEmpty(Cells(1, i)) Then
            Worksheets("Worksheet2").Range(Cells(1,i)) = myVariable
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below, to update one cell at a time (when cell is empty)

```
Sub Button32_ClickandUpdate()

    For i = 1 To 6
        If IsEmpty(Sheets("Worksheet2").Cells(1, i).Value) Then
            Sheets("Worksheet2").Cells(1, i).Value = Sheets("Worksheet1").Range("C3").Value                
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

**Comment**: you can use this also without the `.Value`

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub Button32_ClickandUpdate
    myVariable = Worksheets("Worksheet1").Range("C3")

    For i = 1 To 6
        If IsEmpty(Worksheets("Worksheet2").Cells(1, i)) Then
            Worksheets("Worksheet2").Cells(1, i) = myVariable
            'Exit Sub (remove or comment this line to update all cells at the sime time)
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

**Edit**
According to new description given:

```
Sub Button32_ClickandUpdate
    myVariable = Worksheets("Worksheet1").Range("C3")

        i = 1
        While i < 7
            If IsEmpty(Worksheets("Worksheet2").Cells(1, i)) Then
                Worksheets("Worksheet2").Cells(1, i) = myVariable
            End If
            i = i + 1
        Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, this works to update the table once but when I click the button again the next cell in the table doesn't update.

Comment: When reading your question, I understood you want to update cells click after click. So you want all of six cells update at the same time?

Comment: If you want to update all cells at the same time, just remove (or comment) the _Exit Sub_ line. Have a look to the given code in my answer.

Comment: Sorry for confusion. I want to update the cells click by click but when I click the button a second time the cell A1 is updated again rather than applying the new value to B1 if I am making sense.

Comment: Thank you for this!